# Sort the Json Data based on Value in python

Tags: python

I have a following Json as an output and further need to organize the json in descending order of the sal value

```
[
     {
        "sal": 12,
        "Stack ": "Java",
        "EmpID": "00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000121"
    },
    {
        "sal": 24,
        "Stack ": ".net",
        "EmpID": "00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000144"
    },
    {
        "sal": 14,
        "Stack ": "Ruby",
        "EmpID": "00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000198"
    }
]
```

please help me achieving the same

Comment: you can use , `your_list = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x.get('sal'), reverse=True) `, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`sorted` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) using a specific `key` for sorting, like this:

```
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: d['sal'], reverse=True)
```

Edit:

However, a question like this one was already answered here with some more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050/6279885

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the JSON data based on the value of the `sal` key

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x["sal"])
```